# Keyframe CSS loads only once

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyframe

I have some progress bar in CSS like this:

```
.progress-value {
  animation: load 2s normal forwards;
  background: #b4b6ff;
  height: 20px;
  width: 0;
}

@keyframes load {
  0% { width: 0; }
}
```

And then when user click on some buttons:

First button

```
document.getElementById('progres-bar-1').style = `width:50%;`;
```

Second button

```
document.getElementById('progres-bar-1').style = `width:20%;`;
```

Third button

```
document.getElementById('progres-bar-1').style = `width:80%;`;
```

But the problem is that keyframe load is loading only on pressing the first button and if I press on another button the effect is not reloading it's simply shown the width.

Comment: Would be nice to see a [mre] of this, with the HTML and the rest of the JavaScript. You probably want `transition` rather than `animation` for this purpose.

Comment: Post your html as well

Comment: Once a CSS animation has run, it has run. If you want it to run again you have to unset it e.g. on animationend before any resetting.